# How to convert resultset into int for query

Tags: java

I am fetching data from "1st table" and storing it into resultsset. Now I want to insert the fetched data into "2nd table"

The problem is that "2nd table" only takes int values.

I tried:

```
while (rs.next()) 
    {
        int g = rs.getInt(1);
    }
```

and

```
    int g = Integer.parseInt(rs);
```

but it's giving me error `java.lang.NumberFormatException` for input string: `"com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet@39badcaa"`

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));`

```
String sql1="SELECT Id FROM kiosk_manager WHERE Kiosk_Centre='"+Uareacode+"'";
stmt1=con.createStatement(); 
rs=stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
int parseInt = 0;
while (rs.next()) { parseInt=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)); }
sql="INSERT INTO consumer(KioskManager_Id)VALUES("+parseInt+")"
```

Comment: String sql1 = "SELECT Id FROM kiosk_manager WHERE Kiosk_Centre = '" +Uareacode+ "'";

Comment: while (rs.next()) 
        {
                int parseInt = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
        }

Comment: sql = "INSERT INTO consumer (KioskManager_Id ) VALUES('" +parseInt+ "')";

Comment: The posted answer should work as rs.getString(1) would return the column value as String which is then converted using Integer.parseInt() to convert into int for inserting into second table.

Comment: but it is not recognizing variable parseint in 2nd table

Comment: Why ' (single quotes) for integer values in your insert query??? Only strings should have in the query.

Comment: Does your second insert statement is with in while loop or outside of while loop? Please post your exact code snippet to answer your question better.

Comment: its saying to create a local variable parseInt and initializing it. Then it is pssing that initialized value and not the result of 1st query

Comment: Can you please post your complete code snippet where these two actions are performed?? It is very difficult to understand the problem with your description. If second insert query is outside of while loop, parseInt will not be visible at all as its scope was limited to while loop.. Please revisit your code with debugging or post the exact code snippet where you have problem...

Comment: String sql1="SELECT Id FROM kiosk_manager WHERE Kiosk_Centre='"+Uareacode+"'";
stmt1=con.createStatement();
rs=stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
while (rs.next()) 
{
int parseInt=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
}
sql="INSERT INTO consumer(KioskManager_Id)VALUES("+parseInt+")";

Answer (score 0):

Your resultset is returning a String which cannot be converted to Integer

Try this:

```
 while (rs.next()) {
    String str = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        int g = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
```

Now Insert into the Db like

```
insert into mytable (myintfield)values(g);
```

Please check also that str is not returning null string value.

if the str value is for example "SE" this will not get converted. Please print out the Value getting returned first and confirm that it is a digit although in String format;

if the Value returned is for example "2"

Just do

```
int myint = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Comment: it is returning integer value.

Comment: If it is returning Integer Value `int myint = Integer.parseInt(str);` should be able to convert in into an integer then insert the value into the database; for example `insert into mytable(myintfield)values(myint)`

Comment: Please Check also that it is not returning a null String

Comment: Please Post your Code so that we can look at it Maybe the Problem is somewhere Else.